# How to have a Java application get the latest version of itself?

Tags: java, networking, deployment, installation, automatic-updates

I would like to make an update finder, so to speak. The client application would send a request to the server, get the latest version, and return it to the user in the form of a prompt:

> There is a new update, `X.x`. Would you like to update?

Something of that nature. How would I go about doing this?

Also, if possible, please don't suggest API's unless it is either really necessary or it would be really hard for a beginner to understand. I would like to keep my project working with core Java packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at Java Web Start?

> Updates to a Java Web Start application are automatically downloaded when the application is run standalone from the user's desktop.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know Oracle had things like this.

Comment: See also the [JWS info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for a good overview.

Comment: Ha! Oracle bought it from Sun.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this easily in Java is to use [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/).

Comment: See also the [JWS info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for a good overview.